# Manual hdbios Entry in Refind

Tags: refind

I have a Multiboot Setup on 2 Hardisks using Refind.
HDD 1 has GPT Partition Scheme and it has UEFI Supported Operating Systems.
HDD 2 has MBR Partition Scheme and has Windows XP Installed along with 1 Data Partition.
UEFI Supported Operating Systems Boot fine using the Refind.
When I enabled **scanfor hdbios**, there was an entry for Boot Legacy from HDD 2, and successfully booted into Windows XP.
My Question is that Can I add a MANUAL Entry for "BOOT FROM HDD 2 using HDBIOS" and name it something like "Windows XP" ? Instead of Refind searching for All Possible Options to boot from, in hdbios.
Moreover, is there any possibility to Boot an MBR-Based Partition, such as HD(1,1) or (HD1,2) using HDBIOS, by loading the Partition Boot Sector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rEFInd does not support manual boot stanzas for BIOS/CSM/legacy booting.

On Macs, rEFInd's BIOS-mode boot code enables booting a specific partition; but on UEFI-based PCs, rEFInd cannot do this. The reason has to do with differences in how each EFI's CSM works. It may to be possible to add partition-specific booting to UEFI-based PCs, but I don't know how.

At this point in time, I see little point in devoting effort to significantly improving or updating rEFInd's BIOS-mode boot support, since that's the old way of booting, which is a niche feature today and will almost certainly become *less* important in the future, particularly on UEFI-based PCs. (Note that I'm rEFInd's maintainer.) That said, if somebody wanted to see improvements in that area and so made improvements and submitted them as a patch, I'd be happy to consider including those improvements in rEFInd. I simply am not motivated to devote much time to the issue myself.

Comment: Thanks Rod. I have downloaded the source Code and I will look into it in more details. btw Is there any way I can edit the name of this Automatic Entry **Boot from HDD 2**, may be in source Code ?

Comment: The name for BIOS-mode boots is generated by the firmware and reported by rEFInd. In principle, rEFInd could edit and "translate" that, but it doesn't support doing so now.